# Bug in jqGrid 5.5.0

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm getting a bug in JqGrid 5.5.0 version. If I try in the android view, the overflow-x is slower than when I used the 5.3.0 version. But it's only in android view, if I try in desktop view, it's no problem. These bugs happen to versions above 5.4.0. If I use a version under the JqGrid 5.4.0 one, the overflow-x, these bugs won't happen.

Maybe you can provide me some help about these bugs, because the version 5.5.0 is very important to me.
[if you want a example of these bugs, i'll give you an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuMTl.jpg)

Comment: Especially for bugs, maybe it is better (if you want help) to publish your problem in the support page of the product or contact the support team

Comment: okay maybe i'll post my question into the support team
thanks for the answer